# How to implement system call in ARM64?

Tags: arm, system-calls, arm64

I am working with arm64 assembly coding and I want to implement system calls using svc instruction . I can't find any working arm64 system call implementation online.Also, I can't find the system call list for arm64. Also explain the implementation .

Comment: This depends on the OS you're using. Which one are you writing code for?

Comment: I am on amd64 linux and i am writing for aarch64 linux.

Comment: This blog explains the complete flow of system call in ARM64. May be useful to you.
[http://eastrivervillage.com/Anatomy-of-Linux-system-call-in-ARM64/](http://eastrivervillage.com/Anatomy-of-Linux-system-call-in-ARM64/)

Comment: This is where the syscall number table is located: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/arm64-syscalls-table/18834#18834

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass six arguments in `x0` to `x5`, return value is saved in `x0`.

To give an assembler snippet, this is `write` syscall from [Android Bionic's libc implementation](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/arch-arm64/syscalls/write.S). `write`'s three arguments would already be in `x0-x2`. Syscall number is passed in `x8`.

```
/* Generated by gensyscalls.py. Do not edit. */

#include <private/bionic_asm.h>

    .hidden __set_errno

ENTRY(write)
    mov     x8, __NR_write
    svc     #0

    cmn     x0, #(MAX_ERRNO + 1)
    cneg    x0, x0, hi
    b.hi    __set_errno

    ret
END(write)
```

Give [AArch64 ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html) a look.

Newer generation of architectures all use numbers from [include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h).

You can also check [arch/arm64/include/asm/syscall.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/include/asm/syscall.h) for argument and return value handling.

### Another example:

If you have `as` and `ld` in hand, you can create a simple executable just quitting with an exit value.

Here `42` is our return value and `93` is `exit` [system call](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h).

```
$cat answer.s
 .global _start
 _start:
 mov x0, #42
 mov x8, #93
 svc #0
$as answer.s -o answer.o
$ld answer.o -o answer
$./answer
$echo $?
42
```

Comment: can you also give the list of system call with syscall numbers?

Comment: @in3o added some extra.

Comment: can you please clarify what type of Newer generation of architectures are you talking about ? x86_64 has different syscall list.

Comment: "arc, arm64, c6x,
hexagon, metag, openrisc, score, tile, unicore32" reference: https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/3/248