# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B ARM assembly Illegal Instruction (Core Dumped)

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, arm64, archlinux-arm

I am messing around with my new raspberry pi and I am fairly new to assembly. I have scoured Google and SO for a solution to this, and this was the closest I got to having a running program.

main.s (comments are from explanations I've found on the internet)

```
.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    mov x0, #0 // return value 0 for success
    mov x7, #1 // 1 is exit in the vector table
    svc 0      // execute the system call to exit the program
```

I then assemble with `as main.s -o main.o` and link with `ld main.o -o main`. Running with `./main` outputs "Illegal instruction (core dumped)".

It's a Raspberry Pi Model B running [ARM Arch Linux](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3) on a 64-bit quad-core ARM Cortex-A53.

Goal: Have an ARM assembly program compiled and linked with only `as` and `ld` that will exit successfully

Comment: Try adding this to the top `.section .text`

Comment: @user8908459 same result :(

Comment: Got a chance to look at this closer. You are moving the value 0 to memory address 0. You can't just write to arbitrary memory locations. The program is failing because it is trying to write to a memory region that it does not own. Try moving it to a valid register instead. `mov r1, #0`

Comment: Use `strace ./main` to trace system calls.  Perhaps it faults after `svc 0` returns with failure instead of exiting (so execution falls into whatever's next).  But IDK the AArch64 system-call ABI so IDK if `svc 0` is even the right instruction.  I think it is for 32-bit ARM.

Comment: @PeterCordes you just saved the day. I read `man syscall`. Turns out on arm64, it's x8 that you put the argument in, and I was doing random googling and found <a href="https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/master/src/arch-aarch64-syscalls.c">this random github</a> which had, under "exit" the number 93. I'll put the solution in the question for future suckers. Again, thank you for your wisdom.

Comment: Post the answer *as an answer*, and roll back your edit to the question.  That's how we do things on Stack Overflow.  There's an "answer my own question" button for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the man page for `syscall`, it states that the arm64 architecture calling convention for syscalls is: "argument: x8" and "instruction: svc #0". On [this github project](https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/master/src/arch-aarch64-syscalls.c), the syscall argument for 'exit' is defined as '93'. Therefore, this is a working, exiting, and succeeding arm program compiled using only `as` and `ld`...

```
.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    mov x0, #0  // exit with status 0
    mov x8, #93 // svc argument goes in x8, and the argument for 'exit' is 93
    svc #0      // executes a syscall in arm64
```

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432097/3473629) on SO with useful info on system calls

Comment: `x0` is also the first arg to a system call.  Right now you're making a `sys_exit(x0)` system call with x0 set to whatever value it has at the beginning of `_start`.  Linux (the kernel) zeros registers before starting a fresh process, but if you dynamically linked your process the dynamic linker might leave it non-zero.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are super right, I have changed it

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the value 0 to memory address 0. You can't just write to arbitrary memory locations. The program is failing because it is trying to write to a memory region that it does not own. Try moving it to a valid register instead.

There are also plenty of good tutorials:

https://azeria-labs.com/writing-arm-assembly-part-1/

http://www.peter-cockerell.net/aalp/html/frames.html

https://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/asm.htm

And videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm6v9UyhCkA

Comment: I changed it to x0 because every time I used r0, `as` would give me `Error: operand 1 must be an integer register -- \`mov r1,#0\``. I'm sure that has something to do with the problem. Would that be like an `as` configuration issue, or am I missing something with Arch Linux?

Comment: When using gdb, it gets to the svc line and says "0x0000000000400084 in ?? ()" and the "Cannot find bounds of current function"

Comment: @ibstevieb123:  AArch64 doesn't have an `r1` register.  32-bit registers are named like `w1`, and 64-bit registers are named like `x1`.  This answer is wrong.  I don't see a store to memory in those instructions.

Comment: @ibstevieb123: Use `layout reg` in GDB to get a disassembly window that disassembles around the current instruction pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Whoa! I didn't know that was a thing. I did it and it looks like when it does the `svc` instruction, it outputs "0x0400084 in ?? ()" and then it just moves right past it to a (junk) instruction which produces "Cannot find bounds of current function". I suppose it would then just keep doing that until it went out of the bounds of the program causing a processor exception which produced the "Illegal instruction (core dumped)". Wow. Thank you so much for showing me that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.section .text
.global _start

_start:
    //mov r0, #0 // ARM 32-bit version
    mov x0, #0   // ARM 64-bit version
    //mov r7, #1 // ARM 32-bit version of this (Raspbian)
    mov x8, #93  // ARM 64-bit version of this (Ubuntu 64-bit, Arch64)
    svc 0        // execute the system call to exit the program
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply a question with just code, try to describe it a little bit.

Comment: The only thing this adds vs. the accepted answer is the fact that Raspbian uses 32-bit mode.