# Syscall invoke in Aarch64 assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, system-calls, arm64

I am working on a syscall handler function for an Aarch64 arm bit cpu, and I was looking at how it is done in x86 assembly, but I am unable to figure out how it would be done in Aarch64 assembly.

I was looking at this example on github: https://github.com/rockytriton/LLD/blob/main/linux_os/part1/src/start.S which is written in x86 assembly.

```
.globl _syscall
_syscall:
    movq %rdi, %rax
    movq %rsi, %rdi
    movq %rdx, %rsi
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    movq %r8, %r10
    movq %r9, %r8
    movq 8(%rsp), %r9
    syscall
    ret
```

And some online equivalents as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432097) do not satisfy the same function call design. Which is written in Aarch64 assembly.

```
/* Generated by gensyscalls.py. Do not edit. */

#include <private/bionic_asm.h>

    .hidden __set_errno

ENTRY(write)
    mov     x8, __NR_write
    svc     #0

    cmn     x0, #(MAX_ERRNO + 1)
    cneg    x0, x0, hi
    b.hi    __set_errno

    ret
END(write)
```

So far I have this code (poorly ported from x86 to Aarch64):

```
.globl _syscall
_syscall:
    mov     x8, r7
    svc     #0
    cmn     x0, #(4095 + 1)
    cneg    x0, x0, hi
    ret
```

It does **not work**, but I have tried nonetheless, ironically when I assemble it, it doesn't seem to like the register name of `r7`, I don't exactly understand why, as that should be a parameter of the function call (see below).

I have a layout for the function in a header file for my C program as so: `unsigned long _syscall(int num, void *a0, void *a1, void *a2, void *a3, void *a4, void *a5)`, would anyone have any ideas on how to recreate the same syscall handler functionality in Aarch64 assembly - my attempts in porting across have yielded unsuccessful. I'm rather lost on this, as assembly isn't my strong point - ironically this is the only bit of assembly I need in my project.

Many thanks!

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to like the register name of r7"_ What _exactly_ is the error message that you get?

Comment: @Michael `Error: undefined symbol r7 used as an immediate value`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `w` registers if you want the lower 32 bits of a register? So that first line probably ought to be `mov w8, w7` (assuming that you want zero-extention).

Comment: @Michael thank you for that; it now successfully compiles, but it doesn't work as intended, I'm not too sure that I have the correct structure for my own interpretation of the function, do you think it is correct? Sorry about asking, I'm just new to Aarch64 assembly.

Comment: Have a look at Rich Felker's beautifully written [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/) library. Specifically, under: `arch/aarch64/` -> `syscall_arch.h` and `bits/syscall.h.in`

Comment: You do know there's already a `syscall` function in the standard C library that does exactly this?  Is there a particular reason you want to rewrite it instead of just using it?

Comment: By the way, to avoid terminology confusion: what you describe here isn't the syscall *handler* - that would be the code in the kernel to which the `svc` instruction transfers control.  I would say what you have here is code to *invoke* the system call.

Comment: @NateEldredge: More specifically, I'd call this a "generic *wrapper* for `svc`".

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not using a standard C library for this, as this is for my own LibC; inefficient I know - but for what I am doing, requires my own implementation of LibC to be developed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown at the other answer, when you issue the system call with `svc`, you should have the system call number in `x8`, and the parameters in `x0-x5`.

However, according to the [ARM ABI](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases/download/2021Q1/aapcs64.pdf), arguments are passed to your C function in registers `x0-x7`, left to right.  (The document uses `r0-r7` confusingly; this means `x0-x7` or `w0-w7` according to whether they are 64 or 32 bit values.  AArch64 has no registers named `r7` or similar, though ARM32 did.)

So the system call number is in `w0` when it should be in `x8` (or equivalently `w8`, since it will always be a positive 32-bit number); the first argument `a0` is in `x1` when it needs to be in `x0`; and so on.  So you need some code to shuffle them around.

```
    mov w8, w0
    mov x0, x1
    mov x1, x2
    mov x2, x3
    mov x3, x4
    mov x4, x5
    mov x5, x6
    svc #0
```

(You could save some trouble if you put the `num` argument at the end of the argument list instead of the beginning, perhaps with the help of a macro if you don't want to change existing code.  Then you would only need `mov w8, w6 ; svc #0`.)

On the other end, `svc #0` leaves a return value in `x0`.  However, if the system call failed, then `x0` doesn't contain `-1` but rather the negative of the `errno` code that should be returned (between -1 and -4095 inclusive).  This test is the same as checking whether the return value, as an unsigned value, is higher than `-4096`.  And when this happens, normally you want to set `errno` to `-x0` and then set `x0` to `-1` (so that `-1` is returned from the syscall function).

It's not clear how you want your `syscall` function to behave in case of error.  With your code as it stands, it will negate the negative error code, and then return it by leaving it in `x0`, which is probably not what you want.  For instance, if you try to use your `syscall` to open a file, and it fails with `ENOENT` because the file doesn't exist, then `x0` will contain `-2` upon return from the system call.  Your test will negate it and your `syscall` function will return `2`, which is indistinguishable from the open having succeeded and opened the file on fd 2.  You probably want to come up with some other mechanism, but I don't know if you want a global variable like `errno` or something else.

Comment: I'd just return the raw system call return value; whoever's calling this clunky inefficient function instead of using normal system call wrappers like `read(2)` or multi-arch inline-asm wrappers from https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support is presumably doing so for a reason, and can manually check for error with `retval >= (unsigned long)-MAX_ERRNO`.  Along with manually decoding the non-error return values from `getpriority` for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes Couldn't the value be validated against `cmn x0, #4095` (4095 being the equivalent of MAX_ERRNO) to calculate the return value; in response to erroneous syscall responses.

Comment: @Achmed: Yes, *in the caller*, to decode the in-band error return mechanism, I think that might be a valid implementation of `x > -4096`.  Anything you do in the wrapper function runs into  the problem Nate pointed out: with only one register return value, every possible bit-pattern is a possible return value with a different meaning, so any processing that maps multiple values to one loses information.